# information whether to declare or not declare previous US visa in UK application

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, study, student-visas

i have been refused US visa three times, first visit visa and the rest study visa on a generic ground.  i have gotten my CAS for UK school. should i declare the refusals or not also will UK be aware i have applied to US?

Comment: IIRC the questions about previous visa refusals / immigration history are clear. Why would you think that *not* disclosing is an option?

Answer (score 2):

You should always declare the refusals. US and UK shares immigration data and they will know that you has been refused US visa before. So, lying about it in the application is a sure way to get a refusal.

On the other hand, your situation is different for a visit and study and therefore that will be assessed independently. You have a higher chance of getting a student visa, as you have been accepted in a UK school, provided you satisfy other criteria.

Comment: thank you for the response.